# Writing chars as a byte in C++

Tags: c++, compression

I'm writing a Huffman encoding program in C++, and am using this website as a reference:

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/55compression/Huffman.java.html

I'm now at the writeTrie method, and here is my version:

```
// write bitstring-encoded tree to standard output
void writeTree(struct node *tempnode){
if(isLeaf(*tempnode)){
    tempfile << "1";
    fprintf(stderr, "writing 1 to file\n");
    tempfile << tempnode->ch;
    //tempfile.write(&tempnode->ch,1);
    return;
}
else{
    tempfile << "0";
    fprintf(stderr, "writing 0 to file\n");
    writeTree(tempnode->left);
    writeTree(tempnode->right);
}   
}
```

Look at the line commented - let's say I'm writing to a text file, but I want to write the bytes that make up the char at tempnode->ch (which is an unsigned char, btw).  Any suggestions for how to go about doing this?  The line commented gives an invalid conversion error from unsigned char* to const char*.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  To clarify:  For instance, I'd like my final text file to be in binary -- 1's and 0's only. If you look at the header of the link I provided, they give an example of "ABRACADABRA!" and the resulting compression. I'd like to take the char (such as in the example above 'A'), use it's unsigned int number (A='65'), and write 65 in binary, as a byte.

Comment: what are the types of `tempfile` and `tempnode`? show relevant code/declarations.

Comment: Can you describe what you would like the file to look like?  Not exactly sure what you mean by "the bytes that make up the char..."

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry!  For instance, I'd like my final text file to be in binary -- 1's and 0's only.  If you look at the header of the link I provided, they give an example of "ABRACADABRA!" and the resulting compression.  I'd like to take the char (such as in the example above 'A'), use it's unsigned int number (A='65'), and write 65 in binary, as a byte.  Does this make sense? :-/

Comment: @SuperXero: You mean, write "6" and "5" as characters into the file? Or write the value 6 and value 5 in the binary file, like 0x0605? Or 65 as a byte, like 0x41?

Comment: Such as: 65 = 0100 0001, so write 01000001.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, because "01000001" could mean at least three different things. It could mean "0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0 ..". It could mean "'0', '1', '0', '0' ...". It could mean "0x01000001 in native format".

Comment: I apologize:  @vsz - I'd like to write 65 as a byte.

Comment: @David Schwartz - the text of '01000001' will suffice.  So either write it all at once or by each digit I guess: '0','1','0',...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A char is identical to a byte. The preceding line `tempfile << tempnode->ch;` already does exactly what you seem to want.

There is no overload of `write` for `unsigned char`, but if you want, you can do

```
tempfile.write(reinterpret_cast< char * >( &tempnode->ch ),1);
```

This is rather ugly, but it does exactly the same thing as `tempfile << tempnode->ch`.

**EDIT:** Oh, you want to write a sequence of `1` and `0` characters for the bits in the byte. C++ has an obscure trick for that:

```
#include <bitset>

tempfile << std::bitset< 8 >( tempnode->ch );
```

Comment: `char` and `unsigned char` are required to be the same size, and the size is required to be `1`, so I'm not sure what your final paragragh means.

Comment: @BenVoigt `char` is required to have a value for every member of the execution narrow character set. `unsigned char` may have other values which could in theory cause a trap if assigned to a `char`. Maybe.

Comment: On the other hand, type punning between `char` and `unsigned char` is explicitly allowed.  But your comment makes more sense than "odd-sized `char`" in your answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, I'll take that out of my answer… `char` can pun anything.